# Eclipse command to comment a complete set of java files present in a package

Tags: eclipse

For example  Package com.test.xxxx  has set of 10 files and I have to comment the whole 10 set . Instead of running (ctrl+a and  ctrl+shift+/) on each java file , is there an eclipse command which can work on package level for commenting the whole 10 files in a single go?

Note: I know commenting whole java file set is as good as deleting the complete package.
But still I want to hold the commented code for temporary time.
So am asking for any quick\shortcut.
Regards

Comment: Use a version control system like git, make a commit of your files and then delete them.

Comment: @ReneM. :) That's a coolest sol  . But still those are my local changes and don't want to commit , so are you aware of any such eclipse command ?

Comment: Git is local and you can have a local branch which you haven't to share with anybody. Thats the pro way

Comment: @ReneM. +1 makes sense . Thanks Rene .

Comment: Eclipse also maintains a Local History feature, so if you want the classes back you can always use Restore From Local History, even if you're not using a proper version control system or the changes haven't been committed.

Comment: Maybe you should consider moving those file to a directory that's not part of the build path.